# Creating custom cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the problem, first i will copy the code then i will explain what problem is.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CheckIfCookieExists();

}

bool CheckIfCookieExists()
{

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("accpetedCookie");
    cookie.Values.Add("username", "user");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies["accpetedCookie"];
    if (myCookie == null)
    {
        return false;

    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myCookie.Values["username"]))
    {
        return true;

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
protected void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!CheckIfCookieExists())
    {
        pnlDialog.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        pnlDialog.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

so on page load there is panel and ask client do you accept cookies if click yes goes to OKButton, and after the cookies are stored in browser(i can see them in resources) and when i click on other page on the same site, then the panel appears againg and ask me for the cookies. This is HTML side.

```
<div id="dialog-content">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDialog" title="Cookies policy" runat="server">
        <div id="dialog">
        <p>
           If you agree to accept cookies click Yes, otherwise click No!</p>
        <div class="popup-btn-content">
            <div class="popup-ok-btn">
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Yes" ID="OKButton" onclick="OKButton_Click" 
                    style="height: 26px" /></div>
            <div class="popup-exit-btn">
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="No" ID="ExitButton" 
                    onclick="ExitButton_Click" OnClientClick="return hidePanel()" /></div>
        </div>  </div> 
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you've added part about "i will explain what problem is"? I don't see any question/problem in your post... (Note that your code is backward as it adds cookie first to Response, it automatically copied to request, and than you check for cookie presence that always will be there).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `!IsPostBack()` around your Page_Load code like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack())
        CheckIfCookieExists();
}
```

I think that if you set/check the cookie on non postbacks, the cookie should remain.